# where to keep js files in Flask applications?

Tags: angularjs, flask, src

I am new to flask and using it to serve index.html at "localhost:5000/". Currently I have only 3 files: index.html, angular.js, and app.js; and all of them are in same folder. I am serving index.html as :

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return make_response(open('index.html').read())
```

I want to include angular.js and app.js in index.html. I tried this :

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="app_controller.js"></script>
```

But it is not including both the files (which I checked from 'view page source'). Is there a default directory from where flask takes included files? How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flask should know the path from where it can serve static files. Create 'static' directory put all static files in it. And, in index.html use:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='angular.js')}}"</script>
```

Note that there is special endpoint called 'static' which looks into directory called 'static' and serves that file. You can also change name of the static directory.

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="differet_dir_name")
```

Also, create directory called "templates" and copy all your html files in there and use render_template method inside your method as:

```
return render_template("index.html")
```

So, your directory structure should look like:

```
app.py
static --> contains all static files
templates --> contains all html files
```

Links: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#static-files
       http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#application-object

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good answer. For the OP - don't forget that *in production* you should configure your webserver to serve the static files directly itself, instead of passing these requests to Flask. Webservers are much more efficient at serving static content than Flask will be.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it by adding two more @app.route to app.py which serves the files angular.js and app.js respectively. And I used those routes in . But I don't feel that it's the right way to do this. I don't know.